# Failed to schematool -initSchema -dbType derby

Tags: hive

`org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException:` Failed to get schema version.
`Underlying cause: java.sql.SQLException :` Failed to create database 'metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
SQL Error code: 40000
Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.
*** schemaTool failed ***

Answer (score 3):

FYI,

please check the permission on hive installation directory.

**hive installation directory should be owned by the same user that is for hadoop.**

that's how it worked for me.